# using the IN clause in SQL

Tags: sql, jet

I bit confused with the IN clause.

Does this mean select all data from Customers and put it INTO CustomersBackup2013 table. The CustomersBackup2013 table is located in a file called Backup.mdb

```
    SELECT *
    INTO CustomersBackup2013 IN 'Backup.mdb'
    FROM Customers;
```

Comment: You probably want to tag this with JET

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski
I'm following w3 schools a bit to refresh my SQL doesn't really specify =/

Comment: Be careful with W3Schools. It does [not have a very good reputation for accuracy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87678).

Comment: @AirThomas yes I have heard that w3school isnt that reliable. I'm just using them for references here and there. I will be weary ahah

Comment: Interesting looking at the link you posted, that syntax is definitely not DB agnostic - it is speaks poorly of the w3schools to see it presented that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in JET this is valid syntax for an external database and is for referencing an external databases as described by the OP.

For reference: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JET_Database/Insert

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean select all data from Customers and put it INTO CustomersBackup2013 table

Yes.

The example use of `IN` is particular to Microsoft JET and ACE. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295646) knowledge base article has more examples, but they are for an Excel spreadsheet instead of a backup `mdb` file.

It can also be used in the `FROM` clause to read external data.